# Unable to detect current latitude and longitude of the user using react native

Tags: react-native, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I try to fetch the latitude and longitude of the user.I receive latitude and longitude as Zero and also did not get any permission notification to access location services.Though it is been added to info.plist.Have added the 3 key value pairs for location in info.plist and also enabled the location updates in capabilities.

Tried using geolocation and wanted to show the latitude and longitude on the screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, PermissionsAndroid, Alert, Platform } from 'react-native';

export async function request_device_location_runtime_permission() {

  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        'title': 'ReactNativeCode Location Permission',
        'message': 'ReactNativeCode App needs access to your location '
      }
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

      Alert.alert("Location Permission Granted.");
    }
    else {

      Alert.alert("Location Permission Not Granted");

    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
  }
}

export default class Project extends Component {

  constructor(){

    super()

    this.state={

      latitude : 0,
      longitude : 0,
      error : null

    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {

    if(Platform.OS === 'android')
    {

    await request_device_location_runtime_permission();

    }

    this.getLongLat = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 100, distanceFilter: 10 },
    );

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.getLongLat);

  }

  render() {

    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style={styles.text}> Latitude = {this.state.latitude}</Text>

        <Text style={styles.text}> Longitude = {this.state.longitude}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer: {

    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f5fcff',
    padding: 11

  },

  text:
  {
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10
  },

});
```

Comment: the timeout is very less to get the current location. try increasing your time out to 20000 and also maximum age to 1000

Comment: I made above changes and now im getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geolocation.watchPosition') error